# SQLAlchemy filter according to nested keys in JSONB

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I have a JSONB field that sometimes has nested keys. Example:

```
{"nested_field": {"another URL": "foo", "a simple text": "text"},
 "first_metadata": "plain string",
 "another_metadata": "foobar"}
```

If I do

```
.filter(TestMetadata.metadata_item.has_key(nested_field))
```

I get this record.

How can I search for existence of the nested key? (`"a simple text"`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With SQLAlchemy the following should work for your test string:

```
class TestMetadata(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    metadata_item = Column(JSONB)
```

as per [SQLAlchemy documentation of `JSONB`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) (search for *Path index operations* example):

```
expr = TestMetadata.metadata_item[("nested_field", "a simple text")]
q = (session.query(TestMetadata.id, expr.label("deep_value"))
     .filter(expr != None)
     .all())
```

which should generate the `SQL` below:

```
SELECT  testmetadata.id AS testmetadata_id, 
        testmetadata.metadata_item #> %(metadata_item_1)s AS deep_value
FROM    testmetadata
WHERE  (testmetadata.metadata_item #> %(metadata_item_1)s) IS NOT NULL
-- @params: {'metadata_item_1': u'{nested_field, a simple text}'}
```

Comment: Awesome... IMHO it is not clear that Path index is a nested JSON, but maybe it is just me.
By the way - for checking against a value I'd rather use the internal:
`.filter(TestMetadata.metadata_item[key].astext == value)`
Where key is the tuple

Comment: Sure, i though your question was more of *check for existence* and not *check the value* type of thing.

Comment: you are totally right... I needed them both (and apparently the impl. is different because has_key doesn't support a tuple)

Comment: How to also select [the explicit value None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548545/filter-on-nested-key-in-jsonb-with-sqlalchemy-with-none-values) in case it exists: `{'nested_field': None}`?

Comment: @van any idea how one could check if a top-level key is greater than or lesser than a value? And further, for a nested key?

Comment: @UGS: Please read official SA documentation on [JSONB](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB). Important is that you need to `cast(...)` to proper type (`Integer`, `Numeric`) in order for comparison to work. I can imagine that the filter for nested key would be `q = session.query(...).filter(MyObject.my_json_attribute[('root_key', 'sub_key1', 'sub_key2')].cast(Integer) > 33)`. For top-level key, the would be one one `root_key` instead of 3 in the example above.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update for Postgres 12+

Use the [`jsonpath` operators **`@?`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM testmetadata
   WHERE  metadata_item @? '$.nested_field."a simple text"'
   );
```

Returns `true` if (and only if) the `jsonb` value has that nested key.

Can be supported by a plain GIN index on the jsonb column `(metadata_item)` or a more specialized `jsonb_path_ops` index. See:

- [Query for key in an element of a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73969448/query-for-key-in-an-element-of-a-json-array/74009722#74009722)
- [Postgres jsonb query for dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69727991/postgres-jsonb-query-for-dynamic-values/69731065#69731065)

#### Original answer for older versions

This query tests for existence of the nested field with the [**`?`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE), after extracting the nested JSON object with the [**`->`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM testmetadata
   WHERE  metadata_item -> 'nested_field' ? 'a simple text'
   );
```

Note that a plain GIN index does not support this query. You would need an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on `metadata_item->'nested_field'` to make this fast.

```
CREATE INDEX testmetadata_special_idx ON testmetadata
USING gin ((metadata_item->'nested_field'));
```

There is an [example in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) for a similar case.