# SQLAlchemy filtering nested JSON data in PostgreSQL JSONB

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm storing Nesting JSON down as jsonb, but I have no idea how to select nested json with an uncertain value.

e.g.:

```
{
    "facebook": {
        "openid": "123456789",
        "access_token": "6EFD26B0A868E3BB387E78851E42943F"
    }
}
```

I know the value of openid but access_token is uncertain.

I tried the following but it raises an error.

```
cls.query.filter(User.auth["facebook"]["openid"].astext == openid).first()
```

Comment: `dict = {"facebook": {"openid": "123456789"}}`    
`user = cls.query.filter(User.auth.contains(dict)).first()`   it takes effect

Comment: JSONB operators: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216125/sqlalchemy-filter-according-to-nested-keys-in-jsonb. To access nested objects you can use `User.auth["facebook", "openid"].astext == "123456789"` also.

Comment: contains operator does not support 'like' filtering, it's not case insensitive and won't search for partial string :(

Answer (score 1):

use this approach to filter nested jsonb columns:

```
user = session.query(User) \
    .filter(text("CAST(auth->'facebook'->>'openid' AS TEXT) = :openid")) \
    .params(openid=openid) \
    .first()
```