# sqlalchemy, filter a json column containing an array

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table with a json column "contact_info", the structure of this column is usually this:

```
{
    "telephones":[
        {"telephone":54435345,"type":"landline"},
        {"telephone":694823747,"type":"mobile"},
    ]
}
```

I want to find all the rows that have a specific telephone,
The only thing I found around json arrays in sqlalchemy is something like this:

```
Table.contact_info["telephones"][0]["telephone"].astext.ilike(mask)
```

But this searches only the `0`th element.

Currently my stupid solution is to convert the "telephones" into text and do an `ilike`, but this is wrong of course...

```
Table._contact_info["telephones"].astext.ilike(mask)
```

Comment: Understand your feeling, but as far as I know your solution is fine :) you can use .like though, should be faster.

Comment: Have you tried `func.json_contains`?

Comment: Which database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In PostgreSQL with JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197813/sqlalchemy-filtering-nested-json-data-in-postgresql-jsonb) you can use the containment check:

```
dict = {"telephones": [{"telephone": "54435345"}]}
user = cls.query.filter(your_table.contact_info.contains(dict)).first()
```

[In MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470239/sqlalchemy-json-column-how-to-preform-a-contains-query) it might be possible to use [`func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html).[`json_contains`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

> ```
> from sqlalchemy import func
>
> # JSON_CONTAINS returns 0 or 1, not found or found. Not sure if MySQL
> # likes integer values in WHERE, added == 1 just to be safe
> session.query(Story).filter(func.json_contains(Story.section_ids, X) == 1).all()
> ```

(you need to adapt and try it out, certainly the MySQL way, but probably also the PostgreSQL one)

Comment: The postgreSQL way doesnt seem the very good, what if I have more info inside the telephone ? like "telephones": {"telephone": "54435345","contact_hours":"9-5"}, it will not match. The MongoDB and the  MySQL is just a nogo since the whole project is in postgres.

Comment: @SteveL: Sorry for not being able to help you further. If you would like me to offer the bounty on this question, just say so :-)

Comment: @SteveL Oldies goldies, but: the additional keys would not affect the *containment* check (not exact match/equality), which as its name indicates checks if the given JSON path/value is contained in the `jsonb` on the left. In addition since `"telephones"` contains a list, the JSON path/value should also contain the list, as in `{"telephones": [{"telephone": "54435345"}]}`.