# Postgres jsonb query for dynamic values

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, typeorm

In the users table I have a jsob column `experience` with following json structure:

```json
[
    {
        "field": "devops",
        "years": 9
    },
    {
        "field": "backend dev",
        "years": 7
    } 
... // could be N number of objects with different values
]
```

> **Business requirement**

Client can request for people with experience in any field and with their respective years experience in each

> **This is an example query**

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
jsonb_path_exists(experience, '$[*] ? (@.field == "devops" && @.years > 5)') and
jsonb_path_exists(experience, '$[*] ? (@.field == "backend dev" && @.years > 5)')
LIMIT 3;
```

### Issue

Lets say if I get a request for

```
[
  { field: "devops", years: 5 }, 
  { field: "java", years: 6 }, 
  { field: "ui/ux", years: 2 }] // and so on
```

How do I dynamically create a query without worrying about sql injection?

#### Techstack

- Nodejs
- Typescript
- TypeORM
- Postgres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Index

First of all, you want **index support**. I suggest a `jsonb_path_ops` index like:

```
CREATE INDEX users_experience_gin_idx ON users USING gin (experience jsonb_path_ops);
```

See:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)

#### Query

And a **query** that can tap into that index (100 % equivalent to your original):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   users
WHERE  experience @? '$[*] ? (@.field == "devops" && @.years > 5 )'
AND    experience @? '$[*] ? (@.field == "backend dev" && @.years > 5)'
LIMIT  3;
```

Requires **Postgres 12** or later, where the SQL/JSON path language was added.

Index support is bound to *operators* in Postgres. The [operator `@?`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) is the equivalent of `jsonb_path_exists()`. See:

- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196635/3684)

### Generate query dynamically

```sql
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM users
WHERE  experience @? '
       || string_agg(quote_nullable(format('$[*] ? (@.field == %s && @.years > %s)'
                                         , f->'field'
                                         , f->'years')) || '::jsonpath'
                   , E'\nAND    experience @? ')
       || E'\nLIMIT  3'
FROM   jsonb_array_elements('[{"field": "devops", "years": 5 }, 
                              {"field": "java", "years": 6 }, 
                              {"field": "ui/ux", "years": 2 }]') f;
```

Generates a query of the above form:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE  experience @? '$[*] ? (@.field == "devops" && @.years > 5)'::jsonpath
AND    experience @? '$[*] ? (@.field == "java" && @.years > 6)'::jsonpath
AND    experience @? '$[*] ? (@.field == "ui/ux" && @.years > 2)'::jsonpath
LIMIT  3;
```

#### Full automation

> How do I dynamically create a query without worrying about sql injection?

Put above query generation into a PL/pgSQL function to execute dynamically:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_users_with_experience(_filter_arr jsonb, _limit int = 3)
  RETURNS SETOF users
  LANGUAGE plpgsql PARALLEL SAFE STABLE STRICT AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   -- assert (you may want to be stricter?)
   IF jsonb_path_exists (_filter_arr, '$[*] ? (!exists(@.field) || !exists(@.years))') THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Parameter $2 (_filter_arr) must be a JSON array with keys "field" and "years" in every object. Invalid input was: >>%<<', _filter_arr;
   END IF;

   -- generate query string
   SELECT INTO _sql
'SELECT * FROM users
WHERE  experience @? '
       || string_agg(quote_nullable(format('$[*] ? (@.field == %s && @.years > %s)'
                                         , f->'field'
                                         , f->'years'))
                   , E'\nAND    experience @? ')
       || E'\nLIMIT   ' || _limit
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(_filter_arr) f;

   -- execute
   IF _sql IS NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'SQL statement is NULL. Should not occur!';
   ELSE
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;     -- debug first if in doubt
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _sql;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_users_with_experience('[{"field": "devops", "years": 5 }, 
                                      , {"field": "backend dev", "years": 6}]');
```

Or with a different `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM f_users_with_experience('[{"field": "devops", "years": 5 }]', 123);
```

***db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2e4335ef717b220425476e7ccddca6bf)***

You should be comfortable with PL/pgSQL to work with this and understand it.

**SQL injection** is impossible because ...

1. valid JSON input is enforced
2. JSON values are concatenated with original JSON double-quotes.
3. Most importantly, each generated `jsonpath` value is single-quoted with `quote_nullable()`.

While being at the topic of SQL/JSON path expressions I use one to assert valid input:

```
jsonb_path_exists (_filter_arr, '$[*] ? (!exists(@.field) || !exists(@.years))')
```

Checks every object in the JSON array and whether one of the two required keys (`field`, `years`) is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parameterized query so more or less injection safe. `qualifies` scalar subquery calculates whether `experience` satisfies all request items. The parameters are `$1` (the jsonb array of request parameters) and `$2` (the limit value). You may need to change their syntax depending on the flavour of your environment.

```sql
select t.* from 
(
  select u.*,
    (
      select count(*) = jsonb_array_length($1)
      from jsonb_array_elements(u.experience) ej -- jsonb list of experiences 
      inner join jsonb_array_elements($1) rj     -- jsonb list of request items
         on ej ->> 'field' =  rj ->> 'field'
        and (ej ->> 'years')::numeric >= (rj ->> 'years')::numeric
    ) as qualifies
 from users as u
) as t
where t.qualifies
limit $2;
```

**Some explanation**

The logic of the `qualifies` subquery is this: first 'normalize' the `experience` and request jsonb arrays into 'tables', then inner join them on the target condition (which is `field_a = field_b and years_a >= years_b` in this case) and count how many of them match. If the count is equal to the number of request items (i.e. `count(*) = jsonb_array_length($1)`) then all of them are satisfied and so `experience` qualifies.
Thus no dynamic SQL is necessary. I think that this approach may be reusable too.