# How to query objects in jsonb with specific value criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to query a `jsonb` column in Postgres. I've created it from a nested java map, it isn't in array format, and can't work out if that is the thing that is causing me to have issues with my query.

I want to query the `jsonb` column for items containing an object with '"type": "Unknown" and also have a time that is greater than 100.

```
id|uid                                 |process_stat_json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
---------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 1|9cf237e8-0c73-4c4d-a60c-30b244789e67|{"Type A": {"time": 500, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Unknown"}, "Type B": {"time": 35, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Parallel"}, "Type C": {"time": 50, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}}
 2|07ac957f-c9e4-460e-b75f-79c0d9c550d4|{"Type A": {"time": 55, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Parallel"}, "Type C": {"time": 20, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}}
 3|8e8ef827-fff1-4ea1-a990-206b557ef27a|{"Type C": {"time": 100, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Parallel"}, "Type A": {"time": 55, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Unknown"}, "Type D": {"time": 70, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}}
 4|5279e6ae-f2e8-4fae-8d0b-9297b5e2936a|{"Type A": {"time": 200, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}, "Type D": {"time": 20, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Unknown"}, "Type C": {"time": 80, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}}
```

So for example the query would return **id:1**

I've started creating a query to search for items with the type "Unknown"

```
select p.*
from
  process p
where
  p.process_stat_json  @> '{"type":"Unknown"}';
```

But this isn't even returning any items at all, let alone allowing me to query them, so unsure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first request can be solved elegantly with the [JSON path operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) - in **Postgres 12** or later:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM   process p
WHERE  p.process_stat_json @? '$.* ? (@.type == "Unknown") ? (@.time >= 100)';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QWwjZlhH)

Related:

- [Postgres jsonb query for dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69727991/postgres-jsonb-query-for-dynamic-values/69731065#69731065)
- [Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196635/3684)

Comment: Your second request is not entirely clear. I suggest we focus on your first request here, and you start a new question with all relevant details for the second. The guideline here is *one* question per question anyway.

Comment: Thanks for that, am getting my head around the operator now!