# How to perform sum on a field in jsonb, and then use the results for filtering output of a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I want to query the `jsonb` column in the below table, sum all fields named `time`, and then query for any object  '"type": "Unknown" and also have a time that is greater than 10% of the previously calculated sum.

```
CREATE TABLE process (id int, uid uuid, process_stat_json jsonb);

INSERT INTO process VALUES
  (1, '9cf237e8-0c73-4c4d-a60c-30b244789e67', '{"Type A": {"time": 500, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Unknown"}, "Type B": {"time": 35, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Parallel"}, "Type C": {"time": 50, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}}')
, (2, '07ac957f-c9e4-460e-b75f-79c0d9c550d4', '{"Type A": {"time": 55, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Parallel"}, "Type C": {"time": 20, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}}')
, (3, '8e8ef827-fff1-4ea1-a990-206b557ef27a', '{"Type C": {"time": 100, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Parallel"}, "Type A": {"time": 55, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Unknown"}, "Type D": {"time": 70, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}}')
, (4, '5279e6ae-f2e8-4fae-8d0b-9297b5e2936a', '{"Type A": {"time": 160, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}, "Type D": {"time": 60, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Unknown"}, "Type C": {"time": 80, "complete": 100.0, "type": "Serial"}}')
;
```

So, for the above data item 4 : Sum = 160+60+80=300, "Unknown" time is 60, which would result in a 20% result when compared to the sum, so that would be returned as a result.

I've tried the following query, but its not getting the into the object to get the time field to sum it correctly:

```
SELECT p.uid, jsonb_build_object('time', sum((process_stat_json->'time')::numeric))
FROM process p
GROUP BY uid;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zOgAb-9y)

I've [previously asked about this dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76676379/how-to-query-objects-in-jsonb-with-specific-value-criteria) - and am now expanding this query to try and get more out of it

Comment: if you want to use json you should first learn about the json functions, then you nest them, if you have a normalized table, you can extract all information quite easily without the nedd to extract the data to get the wanted information,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "old school" way - first flatten `process_stat_json` field and calculate the sum of `time` attributes with a window function (`t` CTE) and then do a routine selection.

```sql
with t as
(
 select id, uid, j.val,
       sum((j.val ->> 'time')::numeric) over (partition by uid) as s 
 from process
 cross join lateral jsonb_each (process_stat_json) as j(k, val)
)
select id, uid, val from t 
where val ->> 'type' = 'Unknown' and (val ->> 'time')::numeric > 0.1 * s ;
```

| id | uid | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5279e6ae-f2e8-4fae-8d0b-9297b5e2936a | {"time": 60, "type": "Unknown", "complete": 100.0} |
| 3 | 8e8ef827-fff1-4ea1-a990-206b557ef27a | {"time": 55, "type": "Unknown", "complete": 100.0} |
| 1 | 9cf237e8-0c73-4c4d-a60c-30b244789e67 | {"time": 500, "type": "Unknown", "complete": 100.0} |

[DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wV1VKBkVDrz6uiXcLYTDmz/1)

Comment: is the sum s the total of all of the time for all of the items in this example? (https://dbfiddle.uk/Zck3DlP6). The aim is to do a comparison for each uid.

Comment: Then just redefine the window, `over (partition by uid)`. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract data using dynamic json path and aggregate it per requirement

```
with types as(
       select distinct jsonb_object_keys(process_stat_json) tn
       from process
)
select p.id, p.uid, coalesce(sum(case when ttype='"Unknown"' then ttime end),0)/ sum(ttime)  p
from  process p
cross join lateral(
  select ttime::decimal ttime, ttype::varchar(20)
  from (
     select p.process_stat_json#>array[types.tn,'time'] ttime, p.process_stat_json#>array[types.tn,'type'] ttype
     from types
  ) t 
  where ttype is not null
) t
group by p.id, p.uid
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kb-WEkRg)