# WHERE condition to filter JSON data in nested object or array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, where-clause, jsonpath

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database

```
CREATE TABLE js.orders (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    info json NOT NULL
)
```

containing 6 rows of JSON data:

```
select * from js.orders;
```

returns

```
 id |                                                info                                                
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | { "customer": "Kapil", "items": {"product": "Heineken","qty": 6}}
  2 | { "customer": "Satyen", "items": {"product": "Heineken","qty": 18}}
  3 | { "customer": "Rekha", "items": {"product": "Carlsberg","qty": 24}}
  4 | { "customer": "Madhuri", "items": {"product": "Kalyani","qty": 12}}
  5 | { "customer": "Srinivas", "items": {"product": "Kingfisher Strong","qty": 12}}
  6 | { "customer": "Saina", "items": [{"product": "Bira91","qty": 6},{"product": "Kalyani","qty": 6} ]}
(6 rows)
```

The following 'select' query with a 'where' condition:

```
SELECT info ->> 'customer' AS customer FROM js.orders WHERE info -> 'items' ->> 'product' = 'Heineken';
```

returns the correct two rows:

```
customer 
----------
 Kapil
 Satyen
(2 rows)
```

However, the following query should return two rows:

```
SELECT info ->> 'customer' AS customer FROM js.orders WHERE info -> 'items' ->> 'product' = 'Kalyani';
```

but returns only one row:

```
    customer     
-----------------
 Madhuri
(1 row)
```

Obviously, the fact that the row with "customer" : "Sania" has a LIST of "items" instead of a single "items" is causing this problem. How should I modify my query so that the correct number of rows is returned. Or is it that the data has to be reformatted otherwise.

Platform is

```
'PostgreSQL 14.10 (Ubuntu 14.10-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, 64-bit'
```

Comment: Convert the JSON data to a proper SQL table, then use standard SQL operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fist issue is that you store structured data as JSON documents instead of plain columns in a relational design, which would be *much* more efficient for storage and queries.

Your second issue is that you vary the structure of said JSON documents without need. Some have an *object* and some an *array* as value for the key "items". (None have a "list", which does not exist in [JSON terminology](https://json-schema.org/draft-04/json-schema-core).) Makes queries more complicated.

While stuck with your unfortunate design, this query with the [`jsonpath` operator **`@?`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) works, because it processes objects *and* arrays at the given path in default "lax" mode:

```
SELECT info ->> 'customer' AS customer
FROM   orders
WHERE  info -> 'items' @? '$.product ? (@ == "Kalyani")';
```

To only look at *objects* like your original query:

```
SELECT id, info ->> 'customer' AS customer
FROM   orders
WHERE  info -> 'items' @? 'strict $.product ? (@ == "Kalyani")';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CWahaHTK)

Requires Postgres 12 or later, where the SQL/JSON path language was added. And assumes [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) as data type, not `json`. The former is typically preferable anyway.
You might want index support for that. See:

- [Postgres jsonb query for dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69727991/postgres-jsonb-query-for-dynamic-values/69731065#69731065)

Comment: I understand that this data can be more elegantly stored in a 3NF normalized table structure with two tables joined by a foreign key. It can also be just as elegantly in NoSQL database like MongoDB. The aim of this (rather simplified) exercise was to explore how PostgreSQL can be used INSTEAD of MongoDB so as to avoid the need for another server software in the environment. Thank You for your assistance.

Comment: Note that this requires `jsonb` instead of `json`.